# nested metapackages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I know that packages can be nested using metapackages so that a metapackage can contain multiple packages. Is it possible to nest metapackages (metapackages within a metapackage).

Best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223928/nested-metapackages/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-12**:
Are you referring to 'logical nesting' (ie: making one metapkg depend on another) or to actually placing the files & directories of a metapkg (and other pkgs) *inside* another metapkg directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mean, sure. But I don't exactly understand why this is desirable. The idea of a metapackage is simply to make ROS distribution easier.

One such metapackage within a metapackage is ros-desktop-full: this has a LOT of packages within it, including many metapackages. It's function is to simply lower the work load for installation.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1